# Namespace in a PrestaShop module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm creating a prestashop module that must be validated here : https://validator.prestashop.com.

I'm using an LGPL library , based on namespaces . Unfortunately all the classes in the namespace file is not found by the validator.
The error : Class ' Httpful \ Handlers \ JsonHandler ' does not exists.

There is a best practice to recognize the classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Prestashop still can't handle namespaces, one of ways how to fix it:

In the module main file *mymodule.php*

```
include 'actualcode.php'
```

in *actualcode.php* - the module real code, with namespaces etc.

It works in Prestashop installation, I'm not sure about validator.

Comment: I got it working using this approach here on 1.7.5.2


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933943/prestashop-1-7-4-module-error-with-namespace