# Prestashop 1.7.4 - Module error with namespace

Tags: symfony, service, namespaces, prestashop

i'm studding prestashop for a futur project. I follow the documentation for create a module

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/use-hooks-on-modern-pages/

But when i follow all steps i have this error :

`Attempted to load class "ProductRepository" from namespace "Foo\Repository". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?`

my structure is that :

Module

```
- foo
    - config 
        services.yml
    - src
        - Repository
            ProductRepository.php
    - foo.php
```

my services.yml

```
# modules/foo/config/services.yml

services:
    product_repository:
        class: \Foo\Repository\ProductRepository
        arguments: ['@doctrine.dbal.default_connection', '%database_prefix%']
```

my ProductRepository.php

```
<?php

// src/Repository/ProductRepository.php
namespace Foo\Repository;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class ProductRepository
{
    /**
     * @var Connection the Database connection.
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @var string the Database prefix.
     */
    private $databasePrefix;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection, $databasePrefix)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->databasePrefix = $databasePrefix;
        dump('ok');
    }

    /**
     * @param int $langId the lang id
     * @return array the list of products
     */
    public function findAllbyLangId($langId)
    {
        $prefix = $this->databasePrefix;
        $productTable = "${prefix}product";
        $productLangTable = "${prefix}product_lang";

        $query = "SELECT p.* FROM ${productTable} p LEFT JOIN ${productLangTable} pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`) WHERE pl.`id_lang` = :langId";
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue('langId', $langId);
        $statement->execute();

        return $statement->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

my foo.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Foo extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'foo';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Jordan NativeWeb';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = [
            'min' => '1.6',
            'max' => _PS_VERSION_
        ];
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Foo');
        $this->description = $this->l('2eme module');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Etes vous sûr de vouloir supprimer ce module ?');

        if(!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME')) {
            $this->warning = $this->l('Aucun nom trouvé');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Module installation.
     *
     * @return bool Success of the installation
     */
    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('displayDashboardToolbarIcons');
    }

    /**
     * Add an "XML export" action in Product Catalog page.
     *
     */
    public function hookDisplayDashboardToolbarIcons($hookParams)
    {
        if ($this->isSymfonyContext() && $hookParams['route'] === 'admin_product_catalog') {
            $products = $this->get('product_repository')->findAllByLangId(1);
            dump($products);
        }
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall() ||
            !Configuration::deleteByName('MYMODULE_NAME')
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Do you see something who is bad and can explain the error ? I try but i don't find anything... 
I thank you by advance

Comment: Don't you need a namespace for `Foo` in `foo.php`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i add "namespace Foo;" in my foo.php my IDE dont accept my extends "Module" and when i load the page she is broken

Comment: Have you cleared the app/cache?

Comment: Yes by using php bin/console cache/clear

Comment: Hello, did you solved?

Comment: Hello, no. I have dropped... the documentation isn’t the best i have seen...

Comment: ok, if I will find a solution, I will tell you

Comment: You have the same problem ? I have create my own module without the documentation but... i’m curious to know how solved it. Thanks

Comment: I did it :) now I will explain you how to do for use namespaces

Answer (score 4):

For solve this problem you must to use autoload and composer.

**Composer:**

Install composer if you don't have
https://getcomposer.org/

**Create composer.json**

Create inside the module's folder the file named composer.json and insert the below code

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Carbo\\": "classes/"
    }
  }
}
```

in this case **carbo** is my name space and **classes** is the folder where I will create my classes

**Use terminal**

open your terminal and go to your module folder and lunch this command:

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload -a
```

This will generate a vendor folder, with inside composer folder and autoload.php file.

in autoload_psr4.php inside the composer folder

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Carbo\\' => array($baseDir . '/classes'),
);
```

**How to use in app**

Create your class in: classes/Helper/Display.php

```
<?php

namespace Carbo\Helper;

class Display
{
    public static function hello($string){
        return $string;
    }
}
```

- namespace: Carbo
- Folder: Helper
- Class Name: Display

open your main file and include autoload.php before the class declaration

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

now you can include your classes

```
use Carbo\Helper\Display; // Namespace - folder - class name
```

And finally use it

```
Display::hello("Hello there")
```

For more about this, you can follow this tutorial:
https://thewebtier.com/php/psr4-autoloading-php-files-using-composer/

I hope will be useful for you

Comment: Thanks i understand why that doesn’t work. By default in a new prestashop install composer wasn’t installed. In reality it’s just like standard installation of symfony. I haven’t try to install composer before you say me... big thanks :)